# processing: how to make things move in random curve instead of a line?

Tags: html, canvas, processing

I have the classic balls that move in a line:

```
class Circle{
  float x,y,vx,vy,size;        

 Circle(float ax,float ay){
   x = ax;
   y = ay;
   size = 5;
   vx = random(-.1,.1);
   vy = random(-.1,.1);
}

void update(int w,int h){
   x += vx;
   y += vy;
   if(x < 0 || x > w) vx *= -1;
   if(y < 0 || y > h) vy *= -1;
 }

void draw(){
  pushStyle();
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x,y,size,size);
  popStyle();
}

}
```

However, i don't want them moving in a line.

I want them moving in unregular curves. What can i add? noise? sin? cos?

Many thanks.

Comment: perhaps add a time variable, and then you can define the new positions of each circle parametrically with you vx, vy acting as the scalar constants in order to alter the paths for each circle.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to have a look in [this page](http://gizma.com/easing/). An easy guide in easing equations with working samples. Note that the same technique may be used for curves in time or space.

edit: forgot to say the website is for flash but anyway is simple enough to understand even if you, as me, has no flash knowledge. And code examples are easily adapted.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want but if you want them to move according to a sinusoidal curve, for example, you could do this:

```
class Circle{
    float x,y,vx,vy,size;
    float sinCtr = 0;

    // ...

    void update(int w,int h){
        x += vx;
        y = h/2 + 50 * Math.sin(sinCtr);
        sinCtr += 0.02;
    }
```